# Scifi novel about space navigation by chaos waves/particles

Tags: story-identification, novel

I just read this book a few years back, but it's a fairly old one (maybe late 80's?). It starts with an attack from some very large unknown type of ship. The main thing I remember about the plot is that intergalactic navigation (especially through the voids between) was done by reading "chaos" waves or particles. I believe Chaos was actually in the title, but I'm not having any luck in my google searches.

Anyone able to identify the book from my vague memory of it?

Edit: Some ISFDB lists provided by user14111 in the comments have made me doubt whether "chaos" was actually in the title, so that may not be the case.

Comment: Huh? First it's "fairly old", then "maybe late 80s"? Whatever. If you think "chaos" is in the title why do you bother with google? Why don'y you just search the ISFDB for a list of SF novels with chaos in the title? (Wait did you mean the 1880s? I guess that could be considered fairly old.)

Comment: Click here for a list of English language SF titles containing "chaos" and published in the 1980s: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_ttype&O_1=exact&TERM_1=NOVEL&C=AND&USE_2=title_language_free&O_2=exact&TERM_2=English&USE_3=title_copyright&O_3=exact&TERM_3=198_&USE_4=title_title&O_4=contains&TERM_4=chaos&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&ORDERBY=title_copyright&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title

Comment: Here's the list for the 1990s: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_ttype&O_1=exact&TERM_1=NOVEL&C=AND&USE_2=title_language_free&O_2=exact&TERM_2=English&USE_3=title_copyright&O_3=exact&TERM_3=199_&USE_4=title_title&O_4=contains&TERM_4=chaos&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&ORDERBY=title_copyright&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title

Comment: All-time list (well, up to 2007) in chronological order: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_ttype&O_1=exact&TERM_1=NOVEL&C=AND&USE_2=title_language_free&O_2=exact&TERM_2=English&USE_3=title_title&O_3=contains&TERM_3=chaos&USE_4=title_title&O_4=contains&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&ORDERBY=title_copyright&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title

Comment: "Chaos waves" feature in the David Brin novel [Heaven's Reach](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/101890.Heaven_s_Reach) but they are an impediment to navigation not the means of navigation.

Comment: @user14111 I guess "somewhat old" might be a better way to put it? I would describe 30 years as fairly old though (as opposed to "very old" for example). Also ISFDB is great, didn't know that was a thing. Thanks for the lists, but I'm not seeing any titles there whose descriptions ring any bells. Assuming those are as comprehensive as they appear, I'd have to guess that I'm wrong about chaos being in the title. I'll edit to make a note of that.

Comment: @user14111 When I was 18 in 1981, I’d certainly have considered a book from 1949 to be “fairly old”. I don’t see why that should be any different now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’m going to guess that the book is older than you remember, and is *[The Patterns of Chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Patterns_of_Chaos)* by Colin Kapp, from 1972. It does start with an attack, and it includes the use of chaos waves for very long-range navigation (actually weapon targeting).

> The plot hinges on a fictional science, the study of the entropic
> "patterns of Chaos", which allows predictions of events with an
> accuracy that was not before possible. Both Earth and the
> Destroyers—and specifically Bron himself—are discovered to be the
> target of an extraterrestrial interstellar murder campaign that was
> hatched 700 million years ago.

Comment: That's the one! Thank you! Looks like it was older than I thought

Comment: There is also a sequel, The Chaos Weapon, sharing the same universe but with little connection to the first novel.